# В заданном массиве поменять местами наибольший и наименьший элементы. Cи

Tags: c

В заданном массиве поменять местами наибольший и наименьший элементы.

Входные данные:
Первая строка число N,(N>0) -- длина массива. Длина массива не более 100 элементов. Вторая строка N  натуральных чисел, записанных через пробел.

Выходные данные: 
Новый массив, в котором на месте минимального элемента стоит максимальный элемент, а на месте максимального стоит минимальный элемент. Остальные элементы массива остаются на прежних местах.

Не судите строго, может вопрос обсурд, но я только дошёл до массивов в изучении Си. Так вот моё решение:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    const int quantity;
    scanf("%d", &quantity);  

    int arr[quantity];

    for(int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);        
    }

    int max, min, i_min, i_max;

    min = max = arr[0];

    for(int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
        if(min > arr[i]) {
            min = arr[i];
            i_min = i;
        } else if(max < arr[i]) {
            max = arr[i];
            i_max = i;
        }
    }    

    for(int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
        if(i == i_min) {
            printf("%d ", arr[i_max]);
        } else if(i == i_max) {
            printf("%d ", arr[i_min]);
        } else {
            printf("%d ", arr[i]);
        }
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Последний блок а именно:

```
for(int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
            if(i == i_min) {
                printf("%d ", arr[i_max]);
            } else if(i == i_max) {
                printf("%d ", arr[i_min]);
            } else {
                printf("%d ", arr[i]);
            }
        }
```

Создаёт проблему Segmentation fault (core dumped), объясните что здесь за пробелема, как её исправить и почему существующее решение не верно. Help me, please.

Comment: Выведите или посмотрите при отладке, чему равны i_min и i_max. И если что-то не так, подумайте, чем это вызвано

Comment: `const int quantity; scanf("%d", &quantity); ` - а это что за сюрреализм? К чему здесь вдруг `const`? И кто вам разрешил что-то читать в `const int` переменную?

Comment: const я поставил чтобы удоставериться в том что значение я несмогу изменить,  хотя компилятор не ругался,а я после про него и забыл так как это не вызывала проблем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int max, min, i_min, i_max;

    min = max = arr[0];

    for(int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
        if(min > arr[i]) {
            min = arr[i];
            i_min = i;
        } else if(max < arr[i]) {
            max = arr[i];
            i_max = i;
        }
    }
```

В этом блоке объявляются переменные i_min and i_max , т.е им нечего присвоино , в них содержаться рандомные значения. Что в большеннстве случаев запредельно большие значения, которые по очевидным причинам не входят в инициализируемый массив. Эти значения не изменяются если max or min значение стоит первым в масиве и так его значение остаётся мусором. Ошибка в данном случае из-за обращения к несуществующему элементу масива.

Comment: OK, хорошо, что разобрались